# Problem with designing one to one relationship sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

One equipment can be assigned just once to an employee or a vehicle, I have two approaches to make the relationship, in the first approach I have the table EquipmentAssigned with two foreign to their dependent tables. I this approach in every row will be one field null because the equipment can be assigned just once.

In the second approach I have two tables: EquipmentEmployee and EquipmentVehicle, in this approach there is not null values.

I don't know which approach is better to this case according to database design principles

Approach 1
[image: Approach 1]

Approach 2
[image]

I can't change the Equipment table, I just need to create the relationship between equipment and employees and vehicles.

Update:

The equipment table just has information about the equipment, the relationship is in the EquipmentAssigned table (approach 1) or in the [EquipmentEmployee, EquipmentVehicle ] tables (approach 2).  I'm looking for an approach where there will be not null field. The diagrams can be read from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a cross reference table Called EquipmentAssignment

it would look like this

```
Create Table EquipmentAssignment(
EquipmentId int not null 
AssignedId   int  not null
AssignedType  varchar(10) not null
)
```

AssignedType would be either 'Vehicle' or 'Employee'  (or V/E whatever...)

I have used this pattern to great success dealing w/ similar situation.

This allows a view something like below to help you easily handle to 2 table nature of the assignees

```
create View Assignees
as
;with assignees as (
Select Name [AssigneeName], Id [AssigneeId], convert(varchar(10),'Employee') as [AssigneeType] from Employee
union 
Select Name, Id, convert(varchar(10),'Vehiclle') as [AssigneeType] from Vehicle
)

select  e.*, a.* 
from EquipmentAssignment ea 
join assignees a  on ea.AssigneeId = a.AssigneeId and ea.AssigneeType = a.AssigneeType
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information : In the table Equipment, which is the signification of the fields?

Id : Unique identifier of Equipment

Code = Do you have here Vehicle.Code or Employee.Unitid ?

Equipment type : (I suppose vehicle or employée ?)

If this is the case, a proper solution would be to have a table EquipmentType with fields :

Id : 1 for Employee, 2 for Vehicle
Label : Employee, Vehicle

Then in table Equipment, you have :
(I shall use the notation : TableName.FieldName)

Equipment.EquipmentType =  EquipmentType.Id (i.e. 1 or 2)

Equipment.Code = Vehicle.Code or Employee.Unitid

Regards.

Comment: I suggest the approach I already wrote. It is the kind of BD structure that iis used in industry. I see @greg proposed a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need any of the intermediate tables, because you specify there is at most one assignment.  Two better choices put the reference directly in `Equipment`.

The first makes it easy to specify foreign key relationships:

```
create table Equipment (
    EquipmentId int identity primary key,
    . . . ,
    EmployeeId int references employees(EmployeeId),
    VehicleId int references vehicles(VehicleId),
    check (employeeId is null or vehicleId is null)
);
```

The second does not:

```
create table Equipment (
    EquipmentId int identity primary key,
    . . . ,
    ReferenceId int references employees(EmployeeId),
    ReferenceType varchar(10),
    check (ReferenceType in ('Employee', 'Vehicle')
);
```

Comment: I agree with the first option. 
I used intermediate tables to avoid null fields, for example, If I assign equipment to vehicle the field EmployeeId will be null, it is the first time I have this problem so I do not if leave null fields is a good practice

Comment: what happens when your client adds more assignment targets? you have to add more fields.